# Difference among 'make jokes on' and 'play jokes on' and 'prank on'

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference among 'make jokes on' and 'play jokes on' and 'prank on' someone?

If they are all the same, which one is most common in colloquial English?

Answer (score 3):

*Play a joke on* and *play a prank on* are both ordinary (as Adam points out, so is *play a trick on*). Transitive *prank* is used among young people, as is intransitive *prank* as an activity verb (but transitive *trick* means something different).

But I've never encountered *prank on* or *make a joke on*.

Comment: Might add "play a trick on"

Comment: Can I say 'She is very sensitive. I don't want to make any joke related/about her.'?

Comment: @Little_Grass That is a different expression. To 'play a joke on' someone is to make that person experience an event which you think is funny. To 'make a joke about' someone is to say something you think is funny which concerns that person, who may or may not be present.